# Informatica IDQ - Duplicating Mapping

Tags: informatica

I have a mapping which Reads data, Filters it and Writes to a result table in another database.

```
Read DBR1 -> Filter -> Write DBW
```

I want same mapping to be run on three different databases - DBR1, DBR2, DBR3 and Write the result in DBW database.

```
DBR1 -> Filter -> Write DBW
DBR2 -> Filter -> Write DBW
DBR3 -> Filter - > Write DBW
```

The database structure is same in all 3 databases.

Is there any economical and easier way to do it other than duplicating(or triplicating).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Consider parameterizing the source/target connections.  So that you can run the same mapping with different source and target system through `infacmd` command

Please refer to developer guide for parmeterization techniques.